# Google Apps Script - Making a list of values that fit the criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Im new to google apps script and need some help
So I have a list of questions of multiple types and I want to pick a specific number of questions of a certain type.
My spreadsheet formatting is like this.

> A1 = questionID (Q1, Q2 ,Q3)
>
> B1 = questionType (1, 2, 3)
>
> D1 = number of questions required
>
> E1 = type of question required

I can already shuffle the questions to make it randomized, but that requires 2 steps. Is it possible to picking random questions of a type at the same time?

Comment: Can you create an example spreadsheet with desired results, it helps more than the example in the text here. Ideally, you would also post the script you have tried and describe where it is not working.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do, but the questions in the Result sheet need to be picked at random too. The part I have problems with is how to copy specific questionID based on the type and number entered in the E1 and E2 cell of result sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gs0ZTZcOVwH4ewF06A36buuvu076oeIn_zT5PnFnsvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with Sheet formulas and no scripting.

```
=query(

    sort(Source!$A$2:$B, arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row(Source!$A$2:$B)), 1000000)), true),

    "select Col1, Col2 

    where Col1!='' AND Col2="&$E$1&"

    limit "&$E$2&"", 0)
```

The 3 lines within the Query are:

1. Seed the query with a randomised sort of all the questions.
2. Return Column A and Column B (because the query was fed the results of a sort, the alpha column addresses are lost)
3. Limit to non blank rows where the question type is specified in `E1` and limit the returned responses to the number in `E2`

I have amended your example workbook with a sheet that demonstrates this.